# Remove duplicates from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
   data =` {0: {key1: {key2 : [value1 , value2 ,value3]}}}`
```

Now I have to remove the duplicate value from the list, which is inside the nested dictionary. Also, the function should be recursive and should pass two arguments, like :

```
remove_duplicates(dict , 'key2')


def remove_duplicate(dict, keys):
    for key, value in duplicate_values_dict.items():
        if key in dict_keys:
            duplicate_values_dict[key] = set(value)
     return duplicate_values_dict
```

Here, I am unable to pass tuple of key, as in the question.

The function should remove the duplicate value from the specified key and append it in a new dictionary.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: you want to remove duplicates from the list inside the nested dictionary ?

Comment: yes, their is a list inside the nested dictionary.

Comment: I missed some brackets, I have made the edits please check

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists/7961390

Comment: the list in the 3rd level of dictionary has duplicate values, that needs to be removed, but the function should be recursive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you have shared contains nested dictionary, So I make a recursive function:

```
def remove_duplicate(duplicate_values_dict, dict_keys):
    if dict_keys in duplicate_values_dict.keys():
        if isinstance(duplicate_values_dict[dict_keys], list):
            duplicate_values_dict[dict_keys] = list(set(duplicate_values_dict[dict_keys]))
    for key, value in duplicate_values_dict.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            remove_duplicate(value,dict_keys)
```

you can call this function using the dictionary and a key:

```
remove_duplicate(data,'last_name')
```

the key 'last_name' contains duplicate : ['GUYATT', 'GUYATT'] initially. After calling  remove_duplicate(data,'last_name') you will find your 'data' contains only  ['GUYATT'] for the key 'last_name'

```
print(data)
```

output:

```
{0: {key1 : {key2 :[value1,value2]}}}
```

from output you will find that the key 'last_name' contains['GUYATT']

Comment: the code above is not working, It is just printing the value of the key, and not removing it.

Comment: after running this code print your data variable and watch it will remove duplicate data from the given key

Comment: I have added the result, please check

Comment: Thanks, also can we make the parameter  dict_keys as tuple, so that I can reuse it.

Comment: as if I want to use, remove_duplicate(data, 'street_address' , 'last_name') can we make this fuction like that?

Comment: If you want to call the function like remove_duplicate(data, 'street_address' , 'last_name')  , you have to use variable number of argument 
When defining the function like:  remove_duplicate(data, *dict_keys) . Inside the function you can loop through the dict_keys and get  'street_address' , 'last_name'

Comment: thanks bro, also since this function is not checking the value if its a list or not, it is creating one. how can I check it if this is a list, and then append it to a new dictionary, instead of using set() , as this will not maintain the order for later use.

Comment: I have updated the code where I have checked for if dataType is list before using set